# Использование vue.js в landing page

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Всем привет. Уже написал пару простых SPA на vue.js, активно его изучаю. Встал вопрос с использованием vue в простых сайтах.

Если быть точнее, то не понимаю, как из одного компонента передать событие в другой? К примеру, есть кнопка добавления товара, на клик по которой мне необходимо вызывать метод addProduct в компоненте Cart. Как правильно это сделать?

```
//main.js: 

import Vue from 'vue'
import Cart from './components/Cart.vue'       
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {ExampleComponent}
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="app">      
    <cart></cart>
</div>
```

Cart.vue:

```
<template>
    <div id="cart">

    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data: function() {
            return {
                items: []
            }
        },
        methods: {
            addProduct: function (id) {
                //console.log('Adding product ' + id)
            },
            reduceProduct: function (id) {
                //console.log('Reducing product ' + id)
            },
            removeProduct: function (id) {
                //console.log('Removing product ' + id)
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Здравствуйте. Пересылать данные снизу вверх возможно через события (https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BC-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9) . Сверху вниз данные передаются через свойства компонентов.

Comment: Проще всего использовать Vuex. https://vuex.vuejs.org/ru/getters.html

Answer (score 2):

Для компонентов, которые не обязательно состоят в отношениях родитель-ребёнок есть несколько вариантов:

- Указание атрибута **ref** и обращение напрямую (по-моему очень плохой вариант - использовать если приложение максимально простое) - [ссылка](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref)
- Использование **шины событий** - создаётся отдельный инстанс Vue, куда вы и отправляете все события из одного компонента, и слушаете их на другом компоненте (нормальный вариант для маленьких и средних приложений, но судя по тому, что данный способ пропал из официальной документации - теперь считается плохим путём) - [ссылка](https://medium.com/@andrejsabrickis/https-medium-com-andrejsabrickis-create-simple-eventbus-to-communicate-between-vue-js-components-cdc11cd59860)
- Использование **библиотеки управления состоянием** - для Vue родная библиотека **Vuex** (стоит использовать для средних и больших приложений) - [ссылка](https://vuex.vuejs.org/ru/guide/)